# Stack around variable 'temp' is corrupted

Tags: c++, exception, stack-corruption

I'm trying to convert an std::string containing multiple values separated by spaces into a vector object.  I have it working (meaning the debugger shows the correct values in the vector at the end of the algorithm), however I'm getting an exception that I've never seen before.  The exception is below:

[image: Exception I am getting.]

I've never seen this before, and I've been researching for an hour as to what is causing this and I still don't understand it.

My algorithm that's causing the exception is as follows:

```
vector<BYTE> ConvertStringOfValuesToVectorOfBytes(std::string valStr)
{
    vector<string> vectorOfValues = split(valStr, ' '); //split string into vector of strings (works)
    vector<BYTE> Hex;
    vector<const char*> vectOfCStrings;

    for(int i = 0; i < vectorOfValues.size(); i++)
    {
        const char* temp = vectorOfValues[i].c_str();
        vectOfCStrings.push_back(temp);
    }

    //now we have a vector of c strings...

    for(int i = 0; i < vectOfCStrings.size(); i++)
    {       
        char temp = 0;
        sscanf(vectOfCStrings[i], "%x", &temp);
        Hex.push_back(temp);
    }

    return Hex;

} //<-- debugger gets to here and on the next step causes the exception
```

I have no clue as to how I can fix this problem.  As I said, the algorithm "works" in the sense that I'm getting the right result, I just need to clear up the exception.  How do I fix this?

Comment: make `temp` an int? I dunno, just a stab.

Comment: Try using %c to scan a char rather than %x to scan an int. Also, don't use sscanf in C++.

Comment: It would seem that you're somehow overflowing the temp value.  What's the user input supposed to be for the sscanf()?

Answer (score 3):

This line is not right:

```
sscanf(vectOfCStrings[i], "%x", &temp);
```

The format `%x` is to meant to be used for an `int`, not a `char`.

You are getting stack corruption because `sscanf` expects an address of an `int`. It tries to use the address you pass as being capable of holding an `int`. It obviously uses more memory than is valid.

What you need is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vectOfCStrings.size(); i++)
{       
    int temp = 0;
    sscanf(vectOfCStrings[i], "%x", &temp);
    Hex.push_back(static_cast<char>(temp));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your algorithm trying to accomplish?

From the looks of it, you are breaking a std::string into a std::vector of 'words', and then converting those words into c-style strings (why?), then assembling a std:vector containing the first letter of each word interpreted as an int. Use a std:stringstream instead:

```
for ( auto& word : vectorOfValues )
{
    for ( auto& letter : word ) 
    {
        unsigned int val;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::hex << word[0];
        ss >> val;
        Hex.push_back( static_cast<BYTE>( val ) );
    }
}
```

Generally, if your not directly interfacing with a C API, you shouldn't be using c-style strings in c++.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the written hex values to actual BYTE values.  So I don't want "0" to convert to 48 (ascii code for 0), I want "0" to convert to 0x00

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking two characters then? Or else you will only ever read values from 0x00 to 0x0F? I think it would be better if you explain what your are trying to accomplish. Why are you trying to re-interpret ascii characters as 1 byte integers?

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<unsigned char> func(std::string valStr) {
    vector<string> vectorOfValues = split(valStr); //split string into vector of strings (works)
    vector<BYTE> Hex;
    vector<const char*> vectOfCStrings;

    for(int i = 0; i < vectorOfValues.size(); i++) {
        const char* temp = vectorOfValues[i].c_str();
        vectOfCStrings.push_back(temp);
    }

    //now we have a vector of c strings...

    for(int i = 0; i < vectOfCStrings.size(); i++) {
        int temp = 0;
        sscanf(vectOfCStrings[i], "%x", &temp);
        Hex.push_back(char(temp));
    }

    return Hex;
}
```

So yeah, I just made the second `tmp` an int, because `sscanf` and stuff like that use `int` as types, and since a `byte` is smaller than an int, that cause your overflow.

Not sure if it works, but it doesn't give me the error any more.

Answer (score 0):

Culprit seems to be in these 2 lines:

```
    char temp = 0;
    sscanf(vectOfCStrings[i], "%x", &temp);
```

This exactly why printf/scanf family of functions are not used in C++ and were replaced by `std::iostream` mechanism. Function `sscanf` expects to get pointer to unsigned int when you specify `%x` but you pass pointer to char, and there is no way `sscanf` itself can validate that. Though some modern compilers can check if values passed to `printf` or `scanf` matches format specifiers and generate warnings otherwise, that does not work in general (for example format passed to a function, instead of using string literal). So here `sscanf` dereference pointer &temp as pointer to `unsigned int` and overwrites memory around temp variable as sizeof of char == 1.